# MemoryError while filtering data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, out-of-memory

I am implementing a filtfilt filter, but I am getting a MemoryError. I have tried with two different computers and the error remains.

```
  File "C:\Users\UserName\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 3129, in filtfilt
    zi = lfilter_zi(b, a)
  File "C:\Users\UserName\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 2689, in lfilter_zi
    IminusA = np.eye(n - 1) - linalg.companion(a).T
  File "C:\Users\UserName\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py", line 201, in eye
    m = zeros((N, M), dtype=dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Any clues how to solve this? My data isn't that huge (1D array with length 3011723). I'm using Pycharm at python win63. I'd be very grateful for help.

This is a sample code where the error occurs:

```
from numpy import arange, random
from scipy.signal import kaiserord, firwin, filtfilt

fs = 1000
data = random.uniform(size=3011723)

nyq_rate = fs / 2.0

# The desired width of the transition from pass to stop, relative to the Nyquist rate
width = 0.1/nyq_rate

# The desired attenuation in the stop band, in dB.
ripple_db = 100.0

# Compute the order and Kaiser parameter for the FIR filter.
N, beta = kaiserord(ripple_db, width)

# Use firwin with a Kaiser window to create a lowpass FIR filter.
taps = firwin(N, 300/nyq_rate, window=('kaiser', beta), pass_zero=True)

# Use lfilter to filter x with the FIR filter.
filtered_data = filtfilt(taps, 1.0, data)
```

Best,
DTake

Comment: To provide a useful answer, it would help to know *why* you are using a FIR filter, and *why* you are using `filtfilt`.  It looks like you want a lowpass filter, with a cutoff frequency of 300.  You specified a transition of 0.1 for the cutoff, which is a pretty tight constraint on the filter.  Do you really need such a narrow transition?

Comment: I'm using `filtfilt` as I don't want to have delay on my signal. Regarding the 0.1Hz transition, I am just trying to be as strict as possible (and not attenuate frequencies which might be important).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs when `scipy.signal.filtfilt` tries to compute the companion matrix. For the intermediate calculation, it creates an array of size `(3011723, 3011723)`, which is roughly around `72563 GB`. It is clear that it can't fit into the memory.

I don't see any other option but to reduce the sample size.

Comment: How can I reduce the sample size?
This is just normal data, I can't reduce the data I have. It corresponds to 50 mins of recording at 1000Hz. If it was audio, it would correspond to ~2 minutes at 24kHz. How can scipy not handle such short recording?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's short. Maybe you can try filtering it second by second. This way your sample size would be much lower.

Comment: 2 minutes of audio data isn't short? I think scipy should handle it by itself.
I think I will lose information if I cut the signal second by second (lower frequencies)?

Comment: 2 minutes @ 24kHz :) I can't comment on `I think I will lose information if I cut the signal second by second` since I am no signal expert by any means.

Comment: Yes, at 24KHz is a lot. But imagine, you record two minutes of data (audio is probably the most common signal around us) and scipy will not able to deal with it - that's just bad. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: *"I don't see any other option but to reduce the sample size."*  The problem is not the sample size.  The problem is that the FIR filter has 64116 coefficients.  That is what determines the size of the companion matrix.

Comment: So I have to reduce the filter transition width?